# Multi-<input> Field in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am currently trying to make an input that is actually a different input for each letter in Angular 9. The problem I seem to be having currently is with change detection. The two ways that I see to do this are in conflict with each other. `changes.subscribe()` from `@ViewChildren()` doesn't update when I use a custom `trackBy` in my `*ngFor`, but I need the `trackBy` to prevent all kinds of issues with changes in one box propagating in another. I could use the custom `trackBy` function, but it cannot access data from my Component. Here is my component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-multiple-fields',
  templateUrl: './multiple-fields.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiple-fields.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleFieldsComponent),
    },
  ],
})
export class MultipleFieldsComponent
  implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() numFields: number = 6;
  @ViewChildren('input', { read: ElementRef }) inputs: QueryList<
    ElementRef
  >;
  fields: string[];

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inputs.changes.subscribe((next: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
      let val = next.map((el) => el.nativeElement.value).join('');
      this.onChange(val);
      this.onTouch(val);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fields = Array(this.numFields).fill('');
  }

  trackArray(index, item) {
    return index;
  }

  writeValue(value: string) {
    if (value.length == this.numFields) this.fields = value.split('');
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
}
```

Here is the template for the component:

```html
<input
  #input
  *ngFor="let item of fields; let i = index; trackBy: trackArray"
  [(ngModel)]="fields[i]"
/>
```

My hope is to be able to detect any changes in the `fields[]` array and then call `onChange()` and `onTouch()` with the joined value to be able to use `[(ngModel)]` on the component usage. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible I don't understand what you are trying to do, but why aren't you using angular change?

```
<input *ngFor="let item of fields" (change)="itemChanged(item)">
```

Comment: ‍♂️I'm so sorry, I didn't know this was a thing. Thank you so much!